# .toLocaleString in Nashorn engine

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I've got this test code snippet:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Object o = engine.eval("var i = 1000; i.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' });");
System.out.println(o);
```

When I start the test, I get this result :

```
1000
```

So, could it be, that Nashorn can't execute the `.toLocaleString()` function? Or must I do some extra work to get it run? I've searched in google, but didn't find an answer ...

Comment: What version of nashorn are you running?

Comment: I use the version 1.8.0_141

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code it seems that it doesn't support the toLocaleString function.
When you call the function Nashorn redirects the call on `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeNumber.toLocaleString(Object)`. This method simply transform the input object (that is a number) in a string representation. Here is the code:

```
public static String toLocaleString(Object self) {
  return JSType.toString(getNumberValue(self));
}
```

This is the version I've just looked at:

> C:...\java\bin>jjs -version
>
> nashorn 1.8.0_121